# Spring-boot with maven configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to migrate to Spring-boot, I downloaded a lot of project from git-hub and trying with start.spring.io
But every time when I'm trying to run maven-package I got followed Error:

```
 Error configuring: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin. Reason: Unable to retrieve component configurator for plugin configuration
```

Because I tried a lot of opensource template I think that I must have issue with my env configuration, but I don't know from which point I should start. I had maven-2 and java-8 jdk and no problem with "normal" pom based projects.

Comment: I believe you need maven3 for it to work.

Comment: Thanks upgrade mvn to maven3 rescue my life ;)

Comment: should I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As far as I know, Spring-Boot requires Maven3 in order to work, so an upgrade should fix the problem.